# Como remover o HTML e Scripts em mensagens escritas pelo usuário?

Tags: php, html, mysql, formatação

Eu criei um mensageiro, e depois que o usuário escreve a mensagem ela é guardada no banco de dados em formato *varchar*, na hora do destinatário ver a mensagem, caso ela tenha sido escrita com *tags* *HTML*, e *tags* de *Script* isso é exibido para o destinatário. Como fazer para que isso não aconteça?

Comment: você quer proibir as tags ou quer que elas sejam enviadas em forma de texto?

Comment: Não pensei nessa alternativa, mas é válida também. Qualquer uma das duas serve, desde que deixe de funcionar.

Comment: Então a resposta do Marco soluciona, troque os < por &lt; e > por &gt;

Assim o html sera exibido como texto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De um jeito simples você replace em todos os `< por &lt; e > por &gt;`
antes de salvar no banco

se estiver php pode usar

```
htmlspecialchars('<strong>qualquercoisa</strong>')
```